# gRPC polling for incoming packets from multiple sockets at once

Tags: c++, grpc, epoll

I am looking into possibility of listening on different sockets at once. To handle multiple socket connection at the same fd_set can be used in Linux. I have seen that gRPC also support this functionality with having epoll based pollset.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/18df25228cfa1f97fc5cca9176fbaef64c0e4221/doc/epoll-polling-engine.md

I intend to call different services in async mode and providing a service at the same time. Therefore, I was thinking about having a poll-set consist of client sockets waiting for async responses and server sockets. It seems to be possible in gRPC. I haven't been able to find anything in gRPC API that exposes construction of a poll-set.

Therefore, my question is how to use this capability of gRPC?

Does gRPC manages this automatically? In that case how can I wait for incoming messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same CompletionQueue should be used for both client and server. To wait for the incoming messages next needs to be invokek.